# Google Place API ошибка выборки мест

Tags: google-places-api

хочу выбрать все места с радиусом в 50000 от точки

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=.....&location=59.928067, 30.321071&radius=50000&language=ru
```

Но возвращает только город и район. Почему так происходит?

Json-ответ:

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 59.9342802,
                    "lng": 30.3350986
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 60.233527,
                        "lng": 30.7349362
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 59.6468681,
                        "lng": 29.4464432
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
            "id": "25582cd056adf792d97a947b79dd45f4eb2de6a0",
            "name": "Санкт-Петербург",
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 2848,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102496816678945334672/photos\">Gurcharan Gujral</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAXN1vvcHCmiohiuXeLS2a5R1_uFC3-hRBtkdbwskzibsdnDYf52z22N3to1sRL4NFcr8ox51kBAAp01H4-3SGq2v2kpYksmeiGhkpGVsUzTbVl2zHPG7Z4QIA9HYs7gnQEhAYNOQVfZWJjXXBjxbkkJaXGhRRi4QWWEUysxot0t-EC4BrErYddw",
                    "width": 4288
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJ7WVKx4w3lkYR_46Eqz9nx20",
            "reference": "ChIJ7WVKx4w3lkYR_46Eqz9nx20",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ],
            "vicinity": "Санкт-Петербург"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 60.0808432,
                    "lng": 30.2556906
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 60.1255121,
                        "lng": 30.3888101
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 59.95165429999999,
                        "lng": 30.0711313
                    }
                }
            },
            "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
            "id": "aa73d4ac8653e8464781d30cf31d650ba6155660",
            "name": "Выборгский район",
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 1000,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110241306564912101634/photos\">Pavel Galishev</a>"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "CmRaAAAA1VzbmcXKiLpycqFHGtMH5py6HDyeya3RYt6JSGBp0CtKcfJ9iyRnUYRfbr4gck4R_06bFxVEpUElh5WO-6vRDG89Zd4O8SN2yddTcUw0NVQfVBQ0ULJrqj_dewhXPi-_EhDIU_nsiOu5R7tl1BxYEewZGhTlncyHD2Tz1caLX4IgKYzI6hA4Pg",
                    "width": 1500
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJwROo_KI1lkYRZohzlad4XhI",
            "reference": "ChIJwROo_KI1lkYRZohzlad4XhI",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "types": [
                "sublocality_level_2",
                "sublocality",
                "political"
            ],
            "vicinity": "Выборгский район"
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Причем если указать радиус меньше, то места находятся. Это связано с приближением?

**Update** Экспериментально было определено, что места отображаются нормально до радиуса 29998 включительно для этой координаты